# Handle disabled Windows Authentication when starting a Blazor app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, windows-authentication

An issue we have when our Blazor server app is deployed is that the installer does not reliably enable Windows Authentication on the web app in IIS.

The app does not start, showing a 500.30 in the browser and the Eventviewer shows "*System.InvalidOperationException: 'The Negotiate Authentication handler cannot be used on a server that directly supports Windows Authentication. Enable Windows Authentication for the server and the Negotiate Authentication handler will defer to it.'*"

To reproduce this I took a default Blazor Server solution, set the `launchSettings` to use IIS rather than IISExpress and turned off Windows Authentication:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "IISFull": {
      "commandName": "IIS",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  },
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:12327",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  }
}
```

The exception is thrown when `App.Run()` is executed at the end of `Program.Main` (this is net 6 if relevant).

I've found that if I remove two chunks

```
/* comment out Win Auth ... (1)
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
*/

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
// ...etc etc...
app.UseRouting();

/* comment out Win Auth ... (2)
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
*/
```

from `Program` then it renders OK as an app without authentication. This would be handy, I think, as I can then show a page to explain (esp if I can be sure if the exception thrown) the need to enable Win Auth on the IIS app. I can't see how to remove the services/middleware that are causing the exception to be thrown however.

So, can I determine before `App.Run()` that the IIS app has got Win Auth disabled?

..If so, can I (how can I) remove the services and middleware that relate to Win Auth? Or - ideally - can I determine this before the first WinAuth-related service is added to `builder`?

..If not, how can I restart the app, or in some other way direct it to show a simple "HowTo" page to get the installing user to take the correct action in IIS?

Thanks

Comment: Remember that default behavior is to use Windows Authentication.  You do not need to set those AddAuthentication options at all.  That would be for custom authentication options.  If IIS is allowing anonymous users, then User.Identity.Name will return as null, so that would be the check.